# "Freezing" / "Deactivating" the scroll bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

My site has what is effectively 3 "panels", each 100% the width of the vieport. A fixed header at the top of the screen allows you to navigate between them, sliding them left to right. For example, The first panel is the default, at `left:0%`, the second panel is at `left:100%`, etc. Clicking the button for the second panel slides the first one to `left:-100%` and the second to `left:0%`.

The first panel can be taller than the viewport, meaning you are able to scroll down it, like any webpage. The other 2 panels are always as tall as the viewport, and therefore unscrollable.

I would like that, when viewing the second or third panel, to not be able to scroll at all (since you would not see the difference—the first panel is now off-screen and there's nothing to scroll on 2 or 3). When you return to the first panel, it should be at the same scrolled height it was when you left it. Any ideas?

Here's a diagram of the layout:

[image]

When scrolled:

[image]

Comment: showing some html/css would help, but you could look at setting overflow on body to hidden and then adding a overflow-y:auto; to each container.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit tricky solution, but you could find some solutions:

```js
var thumbnails = document.querySelectorAll('#thumbnails > div');
[].forEach.call(thumbnails, function (thumbnail, i) {
    thumbnail.addEventListener('click', function () { 

        var panelColor = this.id.replace(/thumbnail-/, '');
        document.querySelector('body').className = panelColor;

        document.querySelector('body').scrollTop = 0;
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.querySelector('body').scrollTop = document.querySelector('#' + panelColor).dataset['scrollPos'];
        },500);
    });
});

window.onscroll= function(){

      var currentPanelColor = document.querySelector('body').className;
      document.querySelector('#' + currentPanelColor).dataset['scrollPos'] = document.querySelector('body').scrollTop;
}
```

```css
body{
  overflow-x:hidden;
  width:300vw;
  overflow-y:auto;
  padding:0;margin:0;
}
#container{
  overflow-x:hidden;
  white-space: no-wrap;
  width:300vw;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  position:relative;
  
  transition:left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}  

body.blue,body.green{
  overflow-y:hidden;
}
.red #container{left:0;}
.blue #container{left:-100vw;}
.green #container{left:-200vw;}

#container > div.panel{
  width:100vw;
  min-height:100vh;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin:0;
}

#red{background:red;height:200vh}
#blue{background:blue}
#green{background:green}

#thumbnails{
  position:fixed;
  top:10px;
  right:10px;
  z-index:200;
}

#thumbnails > div{
  height:3em;
  width: 5em;
  display:inline-block;
  border: solid 1px #aaa;
}
#thumbnail-red{background:red;}
#thumbnail-blue{background:blue;}
#thumbnail-green{background:green;}
```

```html
<body class="red">
<div id="container" ><div id="red" class="panel" data-scroll-pos="0"></div><div id="blue" class="panel" data-scroll-pos="0"></div><div id="green" class="panel" data-scroll-pos="0"></div><div id="thumbnails">
    <div id="thumbnail-red"></div>
    <div id="thumbnail-blue"></div>
    <div id="thumbnail-green"></div>
  </div></div>
</body>
```